# jQuery mobile not scrolling on chrome but scrolling on firefox (android and vice versa on desktop)

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, jquery-mobile

I have a bug that I can't track why it appears. I'm making a web mobile app with jQuery mobile (ver. 1.4.5 and jQuery 1.11.1) and for some reason I have the following issue:

**On Desctop(Linux):**

Chrome v.40 scrolling the current page - working

Firefox 35.0.1  scrolling the current page - not working

**Mobile browsers (Android 4.2 and Android 5.0.1):**

Firefox(34.0.1) - swiping up and down the page working

Chrome(v40.0.2214.89) - swiping up and down the page not working.

Here is my code:

```
<body class="ui-body">

<!-- MAIN PAGE -->
    <div data-role="page" id="main-page">

    <!-- ABOUT PANEL -->
        <div data-role="panel" id="about-page" data-position="right">
                <h3> About </h3>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                <button id="tst" class="ui-btn"> Do things. </button>

        </div>
    <!-- END ABOUT PANEL -->

    <!-- HEADER -->
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#login" id="login" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-lock" data-transition="pop">Login</a>
            <h2> AZMO mobile </h2>
        </div>
    <!-- END HEADER --> 
    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="content">

            <ul id="postlist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <!-- the content here is generated with jQuery -->
            </ul>

        </div>

    <!-- END MAIN CONTENT -->
    <!-- FOOTER -->
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h3> Footwe main </h3>
        </div>
    <!-- END FOOTER -->     
    </div>
<!-- END MAIN PAGE -->
    <div data-role="page" id="single-page" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#main-page" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext">Back</a>
            <h2 id="single-post-title"> </h2>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="single-page-content" data-inset="true">
            <!-- post content is generated with jQuery -->
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h2> footer text </h2>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, when I added

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
```

and

```
<html class="ui-mobile">
```

It all worked.